# When a phrase is inside a sentence, does it become a clause? Also, is this sentence example a simple sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I was reading an explanation on Grammarly, and they stated a particular phrase is actually a clause: "**Because of the rain,** the party was canceled."

> Here is a glaring example of a sentence fragment:
>
> *Because of the rain.*
>
> On its own, *because of the rain* doesn’t form a complete thought. It
> leaves us wondering what happened because of the rain. To complete it,
> we need further explanation:
>
> *Because of the rain, the party was canceled.*
>
> Now the fragment has become **a dependent clause** attached to a
> sentence that has a subject (the party) and a verb (was canceled). Our
> thought is complete. [bolding added]

"Because of the rain" is a phrase. If it was by itself, it would be a sentence fragment. What I don't understand is how "because of the rain" is a clause? Doesn't a clause require both a subject AND verb. This phrase only has a subject.

Moreover, in this sentence, is it a simple sentence, or a complex sentence?

Here is the link to the article: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/mistake-of-the-month-sentence-fragments/

Hopefully my questions makes sense. <3

Comment: For those who use the term, a complex sentence needs two clauses, a main clause and a subordinate clause connected to each other with a subordinating conjunction. Since 'because of the rain' is a phrase as you say (specifically a prepositional phrase), this condition isn't fulfilled. // 'Because the rain was so heavy, the party was canceled.' **does** qualify.

Comment: Which just goes to show how useless a term like "complex sentence" is. The two sentences are practically identical (they'd mean the same thing if the second version began with "Because it was raining"), yet we call the second one complex because it has another verb. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: @Barmar can you please refrain from adding unneccesary comments? I mean this in a respectful way. I'm trying to get answers, and you are not assisting me in finding those answers. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not trying to insult you, my comment was directed towards the pedantic grammar teachers who made you think this is something important.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm still confused. "Because of the rain" is a phrase. In the above edit, you stated that "because of the rain", when combined with "the party was canceled," has become a dependent clause. However, in the above comment, you state otherwise. Which is it? Isn't "because of the rain" a phrase? It only has one subject? There is no verb. Is because of the word "because" that it becomes a clause? Due to "because" being a subordinating conjunction? I'm sorry for all the questions. I'm still confused. To expand my question, is "because of the rain" an introductory phrase instead?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth to add on: What if we rewrote the sentence? "The party was canceled because of the rain." Does this make this sentence a simple sentence? There is only one subject and one predicate? Therefore, is "because of the rain" an introductory phrase when it is written first and then a comma added, such as the first example sentence "Because of the rain, the party was canceled." I don't think it's a clause; I think it's an introductory phrase, hence why I am wondering now if it's simply a simple sentence and no longer a complex sentence. Am I overcomplicating this? xD

Comment: It's a 'simple' sentence. "Because" is not a subordinator but a preposition, so "because of the rain" is **not** a clause, but a PP headed by the preposition "because" with a declarative content clause as its complement. The PP is functioning as a reason adjunct. Since there is no subordinate clause present, the sentence is a simple one. And nor is "because the rain was so heavy" a clause. Again, it's a PP with the prep "because" as head and a content clause as complement of the head @EdwinAshworth pl;ease note.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Why on earth was this migrated from EL&U? Isn't this a question meant for linguists?

Comment: @BillJ — As you know (and as OP may want to know), in grammars other than *CGEL*’s, *because the rain was so heavy* is a dependent/subordinate clause and *because* is a subordinating conjunction there.

Comment: I edited to include the error you mention, not to endorse it. Note the block-quote.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Yes, sorry. I should have added the caveat to indicate that other grammars disagree on such constructions. Not very scholarly of me.

Comment: @Mari-Lou (1) 'Simple' etc sentences have been addressed before on ELU, and (2) OP could include research on the definitions in play. Perhaps not required on ELL (which I believe is the right level).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the research is mentioned and quoted at the beginning "**I was reading an explanation on Grammarly**" This information conflicted with what the OP knew, the difference between a *phrase* and a *clause*. **Doesn't a clause require both a subject AND verb?** It's a question for grammarians and linguists because I'm pretty certain your *average* native speaker wouldn't even know what a clause, a dependent clause or  a complex sentence were,  let alone the difference between them.

Comment: @Mari-Lou ELU is aimed at linguists and proficient (I think A-level students) English practitioners. There are many other sites aimed at answering more basic questions. Is it not possible to retain just one for less basic questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Because of the rain* is a prepositional phrase with *because of* acting as the preposition:

> *Because of* is a two-word preposition meaning ‘as a result of’
>  <sub>*Because of the rain, the tennis match was stopped.*</sub>
> <sub>*There were so many people in the shop because of the
> sale.*</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [Cambridge
> Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/because-because-of-and-cos-cos-of)</sub>

You can compare it to, say:

> *After the fight, the party was canceled.*

You have a simple—one-clause—sentence.

Comment: You're the best. Thank you!!!! <3

Answer (score 1):

That Grammarly article is just wrong, and pretty blatantly so. I suspect they confused this usage of *because* with that found in (say) "Because it was raining, the party was cancelled" where *because* is indeed introducing a subordinate clause.

The author of that post, going by [what appears to be her bio,](https://reedsy.com/catherine-traffis) is a "writer and editor," likely not someone who has any particular expertise or advanced training in grammar.

Comment: Yes! I'm glad I wasn't going crazy! Now I just need to figure out if this sentence is a simple sentence or a complex sentence. Thanks for the help! Looking forward to other answers if anyone can help me figure out that second part! <3

Comment: Of course, you don't need "expertise or advanced training in grammar" to write and edit well. Only English teachers and linguists care about labeling things like clauses and phrases.

Comment: And AI programmers writing natual language parsers.

Comment: @Mira It's a simple sentence, by most definitions of that term, since it doesn't have any dependent clauses. "Because of the rain" is just a prepositional phrase.

Comment: @alphabet thank you so much! You rock! <3 <3 <3

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that the "because" expression in "Because it was raining, the party was cancelled" is a clause. "Because" is not a subordinator, but a preposition, so it's a PP with "because" as head and a declarative content clause as complement of the head.